# Fortune Responses - Web Framework Benchmarks

Tags: cookies, benchmarking

What is a fortunes response?

Techempower.com uses them to benchmark Web Frameworks. I'm writing about PHP Frameworks and I would like an easy to understand definition of fortunes responses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find details about the benchmark titled *Fortunes* on relevant techempower's documentation [here](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=code&hw=cl&test=fortune). They say:

> This test exercises the ORM, database connectivity, dynamic-size
>   collections, sorting, server-side templates, XSS countermeasures, and
>   character encoding.

The term *fortune* that obviously confused you, refers to the database table used in this benchmark:

> A Fortune database table contains a dozen Unix-style fortune-cookie
>   messages.

That refers to [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)), a unix application made for a bit a fun as far as I can tell.

You probably shouldn't worry about any of that when writing about PHP frameworks. That's just the a title they picked for their benchmark.